# Mac OS Internet traffic log

Tags: macos, networking, internet, monitoring, logging

Does anyone know a **free** tool that monitors my internet traffic and logs it in a day-by-day overview?

I'm currently using iStat menus but the download meter resets itself after each reboot plus it doesn't offer an activity log for the previous days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**SurplusMeter** from Skoobysoft.
You can download it from [here](http://www.skoobysoft.com/downloads/SurplusMeterv202.dmg).

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't give me an overview of the traffic during the previous days on a day-by-day basis, it's close though and the best as of yet, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Tomato firmware for compatible routers has all sorts of logs and graphs for throughput like you're looking for.  See their screen shots and documentation online at: http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato

Bandwidth graphs:

[image]

One compatible router on NewEgg:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124190