# Keeping track of all web usage in a program

Tags: mac, batch, web

Is there a program that watches your transmission and reception of data and saves it to a referable file?

Comment: That would be a lot of data. And mostly junk also. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just mean I want to know how many Megabytes I've used. So a constantly updating list of how much data I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/57684/mac-os-internet-traffic-log), take a look at SurplusMeter, created by Skoobysoft. It will track your download usage for you.

[image: SurplusMeter]

It can be obtained from [here](http://www.skoobysoft.com/downloads/SurplusMeterv202.dmg).